# Travis CI connection error accessing docker container running REST API on port 8080

Tags: docker, docker-compose, postman, travis-ci, newman

I am having problems connecting to a Docker container inside a Travis CI job/worker.

I am running a REST API in a Docker container with a public port 8080.  I can verify the container launches without fault and that the container is running at 0.0.0.0:8080.

During the Script I am running a Postman/Newman Test and I keep getting `socket hang up` or `read ECONNRESET` whenever I run the test. I have tried every combination of localhost, 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0 on the endpoints and all fail.

When using curl I also get a connection error trying to access these endpoints `curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`.

Are container ports not accessible within the job/worker?

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "2"
services:
  db:
    container_name: api-db
    image: mysql:5.7.22
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: api_db
      MYSQL_USER: devadmin
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
     - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - 3366:3306/tcp
    networks:
     - web    
  rest-api:
    container_name: rest-api
    build: .
    depends_on:
      - db
    command: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    privileged: true
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8000/tcp
    networks:
      - web
    links:
     - db:mysql
    volumes:
      - ../../app:/app
networks:
  web:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  db_data:
    driver: local
```

**.travis.yml**

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - "8.2.1"

services:
  - docker

before_install:
  - curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
  - sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable"
  - sudo apt-get update
  - sudo apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confnew" install docker-ce

install:
  - docker-compose -f docker/dev/docker-compose.yml up -d
  - npm install newman

before_script:
  - node --version
  - npm --version
  - node_modules/.bin/newman --version
  - docker ps

script:
  - curl localhost:8080/testendpoint/
  - node_modules/.bin/newman run tests/postman/API.postman_collection.json -e tests/postman/Testing.postman_environment.json
```

Comment: Shwo us your docker compose.

Comment: Mapped container ports are accessible on Travis in the same way they are accessible elsewhere. Are the test commands pass without a problem on your local machine? Also another suggestion - if you already have a docker-compose file, make the tests run as another container - and then on Travis you just run something like `docker-compose run tests`

Comment: Everything passes on my local machine no problem which is why this is so puzzling. The container also has no errors or issues outside of Travis.

Comment: I take that back, there was an error with MySQL which was causing Django to fail. After that everything ran fine. Thank you all for your help!